# How to make a field required on product edit page only if another filed is checked

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, required, product-edit-page

I have creaed two product attributes "show member price" and "member price".  By default the field Member price is non mandatory. But when the admin checks the "show member price(checkbox)" filed than the field "member price(text)" should become mandatory but for now the filed remains non mandatory in both the conditions.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need help regarding this "it's code not working it please help me how to specific attribute option filter by alphabetically use in programatically"

Comment: Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I came through this page which should help you - https://webkul.com/blog/depend-attribute-field-attributes-field-admin-form-magento2/

Comment: Arif Ahmad, Thanks for the link. But I cannot identify the method to get the value of my checkbox filed as I need to put a condition that "member price" should be required if and only if the "show member price" is Yes.

Comment: I think you need something like this:
if(jQuery('input[name="show_member_price"]:checked).length > 0){}

Comment: Not working for me.